# Angular2 http post request to nodejs server on another port

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a angular2 app which runs on localhost:4200 and a nodejs server runs on localhost:3000.
I want to post data to the server with http.post but I get undefined in the nodejs server in the req.body or req.params.
**At first, I had the angular2 app rendered from the server, which means I had only localhost:3000 of nodejs and I had no problems at all so it's not sytax problem,** but when I wanted to seperate the client and server, I couldn't make any post requests.

**GET Requests works.**

I have TodoService which interacts with the server, and has the saveTodo function. newTodo is valid and console.log gives proper information.
I've tried posting json and posting with url-params and both not working:
Posting json:

```
    saveTodo(newTodo: any) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('/api/v1/todo', JSON.stringify(newTodo), {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Posting url params:

```
   saveTodo(newTodo: any) {
   let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('newTodo', newTodo);
    return this.http.post('/api/v1/todo', body, {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

And I call the function with this from the component:

```
addTodo(event: any) {
let newTodo = {
  text: 'check',
  isCompleted: false
};
this.todoService.saveTodo(newTodo).subscribe((x: Todo) => {
  this.todos.push(x)
});
```

}

I get undefined with both options. 
I also tried posting with FormData, but this didn't work either.

At first I thought this is cors problem so after some research I saw I need to define proxy with angular2, so I created proxy.config.json file:

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": "false"
    }
}
```

So every time I say go to route /api, I mean to `http://localhost:3000`, the nodejs server.

I also tried with ionic2 to post request the same way but had the same problem.
In ionic2 I added the following to the ionic.config.json file:

```
"proxies" :[
{
  "path" :"/api",
  "proxyUrl" : "http://localhost:3000/api"
}
```

This is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./routes/api');
var todos = require ('./routes/todos');

app.use(cors());

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/api/v1/',todos);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

As you can see, I've also used the cors package from npm with app.use(cors());

And here is the route:

```
  router.post('/todo',function (req,res,next) {
  var todo = req.body;
  if(!todo.text || !(todo.isCompleted + '')){
    res.status(400);
    res.json({
      "error": "Invalid Data"
    });
  }else{
    db.todos.save(todo,function (err,result) {
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }else{
        res.json(result);
      }

    })
  }
});
```

Please help me with that, thanks.

Edit:
Here is the logged request as @jaaaaaay wanted:

```
   IncomingMessage {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: true,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 626,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: -1,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idleStart: 2718,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  connection:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 626,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: -1,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idleStart: 2718,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers:
   { connection: 'keep-alive',
     'content-length': '29',
     pragma: 'no-cache',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     origin: 'http://localhost:8100',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
     'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     referer: 'http://localhost:8100/',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
     'accept-language': 'he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
     cookie: 'Webstorm-b127fad0=32f013a9-8b83-4566-a999-5f35bf7360c8; io=uJyvB9XFivORLmROAAAC',
     host: 'localhost:3000' },
  rawHeaders:
   [ 'connection',
     'keep-alive',
     'content-length',
     '29',
     'pragma',
     'no-cache',
     'cache-control',
     'no-cache',
     'accept',
     'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     'origin',
     'http://localhost:8100',
     'user-agent',
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
     'content-type',
     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'referer',
     'http://localhost:8100/',
     'accept-encoding',
     'gzip, deflate, br',
     'accept-language',
     'he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
     'cookie',
     'Webstorm-b127fad0=32f013a9-8b83-4566-a999-5f35bf7360c8; io=uJyvB9XFivORLmROAAAC',
     'Host',
     'localhost:3000' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/todo',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 626,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: -1,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idleStart: 2718,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '/api/v1',
  originalUrl: '/api/v1/todo',
  _parsedUrl:
   Url {
     protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/todo',
     path: '/todo',
     href: '/todo',
     _raw: '/todo' },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res:
   ServerResponse {
     domain: null,
     _events: { finish: [Function: resOnFinish] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: true,
     _removedHeader: {},
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: false,
     _headerSent: false,
     socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 0,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 2718,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     connection:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 0,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 2718,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     _header: null,
     _headers:
      { 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*' },
     _headerNames:
      { 'x-powered-by': 'X-Powered-By',
        'access-control-allow-origin': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' },
     _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
     req: [Circular],
     locals: {} },
  route: Route { path: '/todo', stack: [ [Object] ], methods: { post: true } } }
```

Comment: Can you console.log(req) in the nodejs server right after you define "todo" and tell us what are in the request?

Comment: @Jaaaaaaay I edited the post just for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer and I can't believe it was too easy... 
Wasted 3 days to solve it but then I found this one:

I defined the routes **before** using the body-parser package, and that's why I got undefined.

[Nodejs returns undefined for Angular 2 request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42431587/nodejs-returns-undefined-for-angular-2-request?rq=1)